# Insert query is not adding values to database

Tags: php, mysql

The value is not adding when executing this query. Can anyone guide me where I am doing mistake.

```
    function addpost($val){
          return execute("INSERT INTO `tbl_postcodelist` (`postcode`, `add1`, `add2`, `delivery`,`round`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)",    array($val['postcode'],$val['add1'],$val['add2'],$val['price'],$val['round'],$val['status']));
    }

    function execute($query,$values=array(),$id=false){ 
        $db=new db();
        return $db->execute($query,$values,$id); 
    }
```

Comment: format your question and add error

Comment: please extend the question to also include other important parts of the code as well as any status ie. error messages. Eg. have you checked if the value 'price' value corresponds to the correct field (in the table column you have there 'delivery')? Or how is your db() object initialised, do you set the right credentials and use the correct name for the schema?

Comment: it is not showing any error, only it is printing insert array values

Comment: it is printing array lik this:Array ( [postcode] => BH9 2AJ [add1] => [add2] => [delivery] => 5.00 [round] => 5.00 [status] => 0 ) but it is not inserting to db